# Word to describe someone who rarely gets upset

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a word to describe someone who rarely or almost never gets upset/angry? The words that first came to my mind were *non-confrontational* and *stoic*, and though they relate, they are not exactly what I'm looking for. The word I'm trying to find describes a person that not only possesses the qualities of being non-confrontational and stoic, but he basically doesn't get upset over anything whatsoever even the most upsetting situations imaginable. He is generally a pretty happy, calm and collected individual. Is there such a word?

Comment: What's the problem with _stoic_? That's almost exactly what the word means.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I don't know, stoic means he is able to suffer pain or trouble without complaining or showing what he is feeling, but I guess the word I'm trying to look for describes the person who doesn't really see pain or unpleasant situations as something unbearable or horrible, but think ordinary of it and see it as an ability or merit, so he doesn't necessarily suffer at all, but instead feel proud. I don't know, I might not be making any sense here.

Comment: Other options include "imperturbable," "unruffled," "serene," and "impassive."

Comment: OK, that makes sense, and while that does correspond to a certain kind of stoicism, it's probably not the usual connotation. Unflappable and imperturbable are both good. Perhaps also a phrase like "unrelentingly positive."

Comment: 1) sanguine 2) lookup 'upset' in a thesaurus, look for its antonyms, and search there.

Comment: "Serene" seems very good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Unflappable**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unflappable) describes someone who remains composed in the face of adversity or scandal, "impossible to fluster."

**Stoic** has the same meaning, but often implies indifference to pleasure as well as adversity.

Answer (score 6):

The state you describe is ***equanimity***:

> noun  [mass noun]
>   calmness and composure, especially in a difficult situation:
>       *she accepted both the good and the bad with equanimity*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equanimity)

The adjective is ***equanimous***.

> adjective
>   calm and composed.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equanimous)

However it would not be the best choice in normal use. [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equanimous%2Cstoic%2Cplacid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

Comment: To avoid uses like "placid lake," I tweaked the [Ngram to look for _equanimous person,_ etc.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equanimous+person%2Cstoic+person%2Cplacid+person%2Cunflappable+person&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). Turns out that _equanimous_ is not used at all as an adjective for person, man, or woman. _Placid_ is historically more common, but _stoic_ overtakes it in recent years, and _unflappable_ is about half as common.

Comment: This is a great example of a well-attributed posting. You put the copied-in text in a ">" section, you provide a link, and you provide the name of the provider.

Answer (score 3):

How about [placid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placid)? 
From Merriam-Webster.com:
Definition of PLACID:

> serenely free of interruption or disturbance

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU! This is a good answer, although it would be better written as a statement (instead of a rhetorical question), with a link to the source you're quoting. See also [How to Answer Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Easygoing.

Seán is really easygoing and it would take a lot to phase him.

Answer (score 2):

**Phlegmatic** is another word that fits, although it fits 'stoic' better than 'happy':

> From Google search definition: phlegmatic — (of a person) having an unemotional and stolidly calm disposition.

Comment: Where is that citation from? Please tell us the name of where you got it from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 2):

Optimist:

> op·ti·mist ˈäptəməst/
>
> *Noun*: Philosophy
>
> a person who believes that this world is the best of all possible worlds or that good must ultimately prevail over evil.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/optimist)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**Cool customer**, e.g. someone who stays calm and does not show their emotions, even in a difficult situation (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cool-customer).

Answer (score 1):

Such a person is also *cool-headed, even-tempered* or *self-possessed*.

Answer (score 1):

A word to describe a pretty happy, calm and collected individual who **rarely** and **almost** never gets upset or angry?

Consider "[good-tempered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good-tempered)" and "[sweet-tempered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sweet-tempered)."

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a conspicuous example makes this incrementally more difficult to answer. If you perhaps want some generic adjectival synonyms for "happy", my suggestions are *amiable*, *blithe*, and the always-applicable *mild*. Another (presumably) acceptable term that could be used in a similar manner is *sweet-tempered*. On a related note, you'd most likely be able to simply state that the person has a gentle disposition.

Additionally, if you'd appreciate a word that more specifically denotes optimism in regard to (and *especially in*) a difficult or severe situation, consider *sanguine*.

---

> ## Amiable
>
> **a·mi·a·ble** 
>   |ˈāmēəb(ə)l|
>
> *adjective*
>
> having or displaying a friendly and pleasant manner.

> ## Blithe
>
> **blithe** 
>   |blīT͟H,blīTH|
>
> *adjective*
>
> showing a casual and cheerful indifference considered to be callous or improper.
>
> - happy or joyous.

> ## Mild
>
> **mild** 
>   |mīld|
>
> *adjective*
>
> **2**. gentle and not easily provoked.

> ## Sweet-Tempered
>
> **sweet-tem·pered** 
>   |ˌswētˈtempərd|
>
> *adjective*
>
> not easily irritated or made angry.

> ## Sanguine
>
> **san·guine** 
>   |ˈsaNGɡwən|
>
> optimistic or positive, especially in an apparently bad or difficult situation.

---

I sincerely hope that this assists you. If anybody has an inquiry about the content of this post, please feel free to leave a comment about it -- I will respond as soon as I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

Cool. Used to describe a person, this word doesn't need "headedness" for clarification. A former President has often been appropriately described as a person who exemplified this attribute.